# How to find highest value and return it from an array

Tags: javascript

I want to find the highest 'conversion' value from an array:

```
var barTextData = [
{
    term: "Roof",
    clicks: 11235,
    conversion: 3.12
}, {
    term: "Snow",
    clicks: 6309,
    conversion: 4.45
}, {
    term: "Chains",
    clicks: 4479,
    conversion: 4.33
}
]
```

I would also like to return the corresponding 'term' string?

Comment: Would you like pepperoni on that?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 2):

A simple loop will do the trick:

```
var highest = 0, term = "";
for (var i = 0; i < barTextData.length; i++) {
    if (barTextData[i].conversion > highest) {
        highest = barTextData[i].conversion;
        term = barTextData[i].term;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I have been struggling with that for ages! Works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

You should loop through the array, saving the highest found value, and compare it to the conversion of each item as you come across it. If the conversion is higher than the saved item, replace it with the current one. At the end, you should have the item with the highest conversion saved.

Note that it's very important you compare on the `conversion` property, but save the whole item, so you can later access the `term` property.

```js
var barTextData = [{
  term: "Roof",
  clicks: 11235,
  conversion: 3.12
}, {
  term: "Snow",
  clicks: 6309,
  conversion: 4.45
}, {
  term: "Chains",
  clicks: 4479,
  conversion: 4.33
}];

// Get the highest conversion
var highest = null;
barTextData.forEach(function(it) {
  if (!highest || it.conversion > highest.conversion) {
    highest = it;
  }
});

if (highest) {
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = JSON.stringify(highest);
} else {
  document.getElementById("result").textContent = "No value found.";
}
```

```html
<pre id="result"></pre>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can sort the array and take the first element

```
var highest = barTextData.sort(function(a, b) {
  return a.conversion < b.conversion;
})[0];
console.log(highest.term);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [Array's reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) would do the trick:

```
var maximumBarTextObject = barTextData.reduce(function(currentMax, current) {
    if (!currentMax) {
        return currentMax;
    }
    return (current.conversion > currentMax.conversion) ? current : currentMax;
});
```

If this is clientside code, Array.prototype.reduce is supported on [all major browsers](http://kangax.github.io/compat-table/es5/#Array.prototype.reduce), with IE7 and 8 being the exception.